# If $A$ is a symmetric, prove that, $dvv^T$ is of rank one.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix of size $n$, and $v_{n\times 1}$ is eigenvector corresponding to the eigen value $d$ with norm $1$.

Prove that,
$$dvv^T$$ is of rank one.

Comment: Well, $\operatorname{rank}(vv^t)=1$ for any $v\neq 0$...

Comment: Why this reference to a certain matrix $A$?

Comment: @Surb thank you..realized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n)^T$.

Then all columns of $dvv^T$ are proportional to $v$, the coefficient for column $j$ being $dv_j$. Thus the [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29) of $dvv^T$ is $1$, whenever $v$ and $d$ are nonzero.

Here, you assume $v$ has norm $1$ so it's nonzero, but the eigenvalue $d$ may be $0$, then $dvv^T$ would have null rank.

Answer (score 0):

By the spectral theorem you can find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $A$.  Without loss of generality assume $v$ is normalized.  Notice that $v$ is an eigenvector of $dvv^T$ and any vector in the orthogonal complement of $span\{v\}$ is in the kernel.